# How to draw a Hasse diagram of a large number of pairwise comparisons?

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-comparisons

I have 100 pairwise comparisons where my results show that 33% of the pairwise comparison tests are non-significant.

- How can I draw draw a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) to represent this?
- Are there any tips to follow when drawing a Hasse diagram?